# Python Tuple max

Tags: python, max

I have a question about Python:

```
tuple1 = (123, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc', 9681)

print "Max value element : ", max(tuple1)
```

Why the output is 'zara' not 9681?

Comment: look at the ascii table, z is after numbers

Comment: I'm surprise this works at all, there shouldn't be a way to compare `int` with `str`...

Comment: @BrianRodriguez only in Python 2, I don't think it works in Python 3.

Comment: @Mark Ransom Yeah I just checked, it doesn't.

Comment: In Python 3, what answer will be output?

Comment: Python 3 will raise: `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

Answer (score 0):

Because it is order by ascii table.
'z' is 122 and '1' is 49.
For this reason, it will return 'zara'

Comment: It's got nothing to do with the ascii collating sequence. Try `max((123, ' ', 456))`: the result is `'  '` even though the space is ascii 32, lower than all other printable characters.